# Is there any way to isolate the python2.7 , mod_wsgi installation from main environment

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django, mod-wsgi

I have many local virtual machines for building the django websites. I find it very hard to configure all the machines with mod_wsgi , python and all that installation issues.

Is there any way that i can install even python 2.7 , mod_wsgi etc and all that inside the virtual environment folder so that i can just copy paste that folder in my live server and i don't need to mess with mos_wsgi , python 2.7 and other issues.

Is it possible or even any close variation of that so that puting the site to live servers is very easy and everything which is needed by site should be included locally

I also face many problems when i need to move the django sites across servers

Answer (score 1):

You could check on virtualenv [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org).

Comment: It sounds like they're already using virtualenv.